# Find $f(U)$ and calculate $f^{-1}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2 :  \,(x,y) \mapsto (x+y,xy)$ and $U=\{(x,y): |x| <|y| \,\}$.
Find $f(U)$ and calculate $(f|_U)^{-1}$.

**My attempt :** Let $(z,t)$ and find $(x,y) \in U$ s.t :
$$\begin{cases}
x+y&=z \\ xy&=t
\end{cases} \iff (x,y) \text{ solution of the equation } X^2-zX+t=0 \\\iff\Delta=z^2-4t>0 \iff X=\dfrac{z\pm \sqrt{z^2-4t}}{2}$$
so $$f^{-1}(x,y)= \left( \dfrac{x- \sqrt{x^2-4y}}{2}, \dfrac{x+ \sqrt{x^2-4y}}{2}\right) \text{ and }f(U)=\{(x,y) : x^2-4y>0\}$$
My solution is true? especially the $f(U)$ ?

Comment: Yes, I edit it, thank you @JohnHughes

Comment: what about $f(U)$ ?

Comment: Why did you put a differential geometry tag here? This is just set theory.

Comment: @TedShifrin In fact  this exercice is part of a problem of differential geometry !

Comment: Nothing whatsoever to do with differential geometry. It's not even a multivariable calculus exercise. Maybe you're going to learn the inverse function theorem; but this is *not* differential geometry — no connections, curvature, or even $3$-space geometry of surfaces.

Comment: okey, thank you ! i will edit the answer. Can you tell me please if the answer is true?!

Comment: the question is to compute $(f|_U)^{-1}$, it was just a typo.

Comment: You should think about why $U$ is in the question at all. What does the region $|x|>|y|$ map to? Where does $|x|=|y|$ map?

Comment: Probably you can write x and y into polar coordinates and use trigonometric formula to find the solution. If you can find the solution yourself, that is really good. If not, leave me a message, and I can probably write something as an answer.

Comment: Your use of the same letters in domain and range did confuse me. Sorry. Your answer is right, but you should understand the point: What is the difference between $f(U)$ and $f(\Bbb R^2)$, and why?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer for $f^{-1}(x,y)$ looks right if $x>0$.  If $x<0$ then the signs of $\sqrt{x^2-4y}$ look like they need to be reversed or the absolute value condition for $U$ won’t hold, assuming you want $f^{-1}$ to map back to $U$.

If $x=0$ then it’s not possible to map back to $U$ since the two coordinates would have the same absolute value, contradicting the absolute value condition for $U$.

As for $f(U)$, it looks like a strange beast.  It looks like $R^2$ less the parabola $y=x^2/4$ and everything above it, and also less the line given by $x=0$.